# Why the megascan's textures are weird?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes, asset

I've used several times the megascans assets but their textures always look weird. The best I had is just not so much realistic (even if the asset is in 8k).

I'm currently working on a project using landscapes from megascan and the textures have never been this weird. It looks pretty much realistic but some parts are very bright, the displacement looks like streched a bit or not so deep.

It's a huge scene but we can see all these imperfections, so I can't make a closer scene.

You'll find one picture from the entire scene, one is a close up of a mountain and the last is my node tree.
It's a bit blurry I don't know why so : albedo is connected to base color. Roughness is connected to Roughness. Transmission is connected to transmission. Normal is connected to normal map which is connected to the normal socket. Displacement is connected to separate RGB which is connected to displacement which is connected to the displacement socket of the material output.

I'm using blender 3.5, cycles experimental GPU compute.

Thank you for the help and have a beautiful day ;)[image]